# Jquery dynamically generated content sibling issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, siblings

I'm getting close to the solution I'm looking for, but have one more issue that's giving me fits. Here is my fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/CjHAD/10)

I need to clean this up so that when red click div is open and I open black click div, the blue click thumb doesn't duplicate itself inside the .parent-box sibling.

Any tips in general on making this more graceful, fluid, and efficient are welcomed, and I'm happy to clarify if needed!

Here is the code:
Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="parent-box">
    <h3>2013</h3>
    <div class="works-post">
        <div class="x-image" style="color: red">click</div><!--open/close content-->
        <div class="works-thumb">                       
            <img width="150" height="112"  />
        </div><!--.works-thumb-->
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <h4>Content</h4>
        </div><!--.toggle-content-->
    </div><!--.works-post-->
</div><!--.parent-box-->
<div class="parent-box">
    <h3>2012</h3>
    <div class="works-post">
        <div class="x-image" style="color: blue">click</div><!--open/close content-->
        <div class="works-thumb">                       
            <img width="150" height="112"  />
        </div><!--.works-thumb-->
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <h4>Content</h4>
        </div><!--.toggle-content-->
    </div><!--.works-post-->
    <div class="works-post">
        <div class="x-image">click</div><!--open/close content-->
        <div class="works-thumb">                       
           <img width="150" height="112"  />
        </div><!--.works-thumb-->
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <h4>Content</h4>
        </div><!--.toggle-content-->
    </div><!--.works-post-->
</div><!--.parent-box-->
```

my CSS:

```
h3 {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
.x-image {
border: solid thin #000;
float: left;
padding: 0 2px 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 15;    
}
.works-thumb {
margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
width: 25%;
}
.works-thumb img {
border: solid 2px #a8b9b7;  
}
.works-post {
border: none;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 2em;    
}
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px 0 0 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    min-height: 150px;
}
.open {
background-color: #eee;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
border-top: solid thin #ccc;
border-bottom: solid thin #ccc;
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.x-image').on('click', (function(event){
    var other = $(this).parent().siblings('.works-post');
    var beyond = $(this).closest('.parent-box').siblings().find('.works-post');

    $(this).closest('.works-post').find('.works-thumb').toggle('fast');
 $(this).closest('.works-post').find('.toggle-content').slideToggle('fast', function(){
            $(this).closest('.works-post').toggleClass('open',$(this).is(':visible'));

                other.removeClass('open').insertAfter($('.open'));

                other.find('.toggle-content').hide();
                other.find('.works-thumb').show();

                beyond.removeClass('open');

                beyond.find('.toggle-content').hide();
                beyond.children('.works-thumb').filter(':hidden').show();

        })

}))

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the call to `.insertAfter($('.open'))` seems to solve the issue you are referencing. At the time that method is called, there are two elements with the class `open` and you are therefore inserting the contents of `other` in two places. What is your intent with performing the insert?

```
other.removeClass('open');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jygEv/3/)

**Update:**

If you are trying to move the opened `works-post` to the top of the set in its `parent-box`, you can do so by using [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) in reference to `other.first()`.

I took the liberty of modifying your code a bit for clarity. It essentially does the same thing as the original besides the removal of the `.insertAfter()` and the addition of the `.insertBefore()` at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.x-image').on('click', (function (event) {
        var thisPost = $(this).closest('.works-post');
        var thisBox = $(this).closest('.parent-box');
        var otherPosts = thisPost.siblings('.works-post');
        var beyondPosts = thisBox.siblings('.parent-box').find('.works-post');

        thisPost.find('.works-thumb').toggle('fast');
        thisPost.find('.toggle-content').slideToggle('fast', function () {
            thisPost.toggleClass('open', $(this).is(':visible'));

            otherPosts.removeClass('open');
            otherPosts.find('.toggle-content').hide();
            otherPosts.find('.works-thumb').show();

            beyondPosts.removeClass('open');
            beyondPosts.find('.toggle-content').hide();
            beyondPosts.children('.works-thumb').filter(':hidden').show();

            thisPost.insertBefore(otherPosts.first());
        });
    }));
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpnEr/)

Comment: I would like whichever item is open to be first. In my actual application, the open item holds an expanded portfolio div, and all the thumbs bump down below it.

Comment: @AmandaLong Do you mean you want it to be the first `works-post` within its parent `parent-box`? If so, do you need it to go back to its original placement when it is closed?

Comment: That is what I am trying to accomplish, and it doesn't matter if it returns to it's original spot. Thanks!

Comment: @AmandaLong I updated my answer. See if that does what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Love the clarity! I'll give it a go in the morning and let you know :-)

Comment: Ruben - works beautifully! Thank you so much for your input and help with the variables.